# How to serve a file if URL doesn't match to any pattern in Go?

Tags: angularjs, go, typescript, angular, servemux

I'm building a Single Page Application using Angular 2 and Go, and in Angular I use routing. If I open the site at, say, `http://example.com/`, Go will serve me my `index.html` file, which is good because I wrote this:

```
mux.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(mysiteRoot)))
```

Now I have a route in Angular, let's say, `/posts`, and If it's a default route (that is, when `useAsDefault` is `true`) or if I just manually go to `http://example.com/posts`, I'll get a 404 error from Go, which means that no handler is specified for this path.

I don't think that creating a handler in Go for every single Angular route is a good idea, because there may be a lot of routes. So my question is, how can I serve `index.html` in Go if the request URL doesn't match any other pattern that I set in my `ServeMux`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that was pretty easy actually. 
The `net/http` documentation [says](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux) this:

> Note that since a pattern ending in a slash names a rooted subtree,
>   the pattern "/" matches all paths not matched by other registered
>   patterns, not just the URL with Path == "/".

So I needed to do something with my `"/"` handler. `http.FileServer` looks for files in a directory that is specified in the pattern string, so I just replaced it with this:

```
mux.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, mysiteRoot + "index.html")
})
```

And it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to change the URL provider settings in your angular2 app to use [HashLocationStrategy](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/HashLocationStrategy-class.html). Using this, your routes will be of the form

> #/posts

and will not trigger any route in your golang app.